# Mac zip compress without __MACOSX folder?

Tags: macos, zip

When I compress files with the built in zip compressor in Mac OSX, it causes an extra folder titled "__MACOSX" to be created in the extracted zip.

Can I adjust my settings to keep this folder from being created or do I need to purchase a third party compression tool?

**UPDATE**: I just found a freeware app for OSX that solves my problem: "[YemuZip](https://www.yellowmug.com/yemuzip/)"

**UPDATE 2**: YemuZip is no longer freeware.

Comment: The existence of _MACOSX folder doesn't creates any problem. Simply delete it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be in AskDifferent

Comment: It creates a problem with picky web services that require a pristine zip archive, so I'm grateful for the explanations

Comment: @JayprakashDubey It's incredibily irritating, and as a linux user who likes not leaving trash everywhere I go, I can't stand `__MACOSX`, `.DS_Store`, `._fileName`, and all the other assorted turds Mac OS drops in its archives. OSX's `tar' does this as well - in blatant disregard for the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: Also see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239578/compress-without-ds-store-and-macosx

Answer (score 132, accepted):

When I had this problem I've done it from command line:

```
zip file.zip uncompressed
```

**EDIT**, after many downvotes: I was using this option for some time ago and I don't know where I learnt it, so I can't give you a better explanation. Chris Johnson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13665552/167365) is correct, but I won't delete mine. As one comment says, it's more accurate to what OP is asking, as it compress without those files, instead of removing them from a compressed file. I find it easier to remember, too.

Comment: This lacks explanation.

Comment: The __MACOSX/ subdirectory contains Mac resource forks and is created when you use Mac tools to create the zip file. Likewise, Mac tools will consume the __MACOSX/ subdirectory in order to set resource forks, and you'll never even see it. However, if you use Mac tools to create the zip file and some other tools to unpack it, you'll get the __MACOSX/ directory and not the resource forks. If you create the file with `zip`, which is a 3rd-party app, then the __MACOSX/ directory never gets created in the first place.

Comment: See my answer for an easy way to delete the _MACOSX folder after the zip file is created.

Comment: To compress a directory recursively without __MACOSX and other: `zip -rX file.zip uncompressed_directory`

Comment: prevention is better than cure, and simple is better than complicated. Now if we add this a an Automator service we have ourselves a productivity beast here. Great solution.

Answer (score 421):

Can be fixed after the fact by `zip -d filename.zip __MACOSX/\*`

And, to also delete `.DS_Store` files: `zip -d filename.zip \*/.DS_Store`

Comment: to also delete .DS_Store files: `zip -d filename.zip \*/.DS_Store`

Comment: The accepted answer says how not to get the __MACOSX/ directory in the first place, but says nothing about what to do with an existing .zip file. This answer says how to get rid of __MACOSX/ if you've already got it. However, the original question was how not to get it in the first place, so the accepted answer is the correct one.

Comment: How might I do this recursively for all zip files?

Comment: To apply to all zip files under some root: `find ~ -type f -name '*.zip' -exec zip -d '{}' __MACOSX/\* \;`. Substitute your starting point for `~`.

Comment: A function to remove all junk files: `cleanzip(){ zip -d $1 $2 __MACOSX/\* \*/.DS_Store; }`. Usage: `cleanzip file.zip` or `cleanzip file.zip MORE_JUNK_FILES` (second parameter is optional)

Comment: @mrdaliri, note (1) it is unsafe to reference file path parameters without double-quoting them, and (2) there is no reason to limit to 2 parameters. Better to change your `$1 $2` to just `"$@"`.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on why `\*/` or `/\*` must be used?

Comment: You want the zip utility to interpret the wildcard, not the shell. The backslash escapes the asterisk so it isn't interpreted as a glob by the shell. You can use either `\*` or `'*'` (but not `"^"`) with the same effect.

Comment: Something is not OK with the `zip` command when used like https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239578/compress-without-ds-store-and-macosx If you unzip it later with PHP's `extractTo`, the extracted folder will not be named like the original zip. It will instead be named with the name given to the zip when `fopen`ed. However, if you zip the file with Mac finder, then that extracted folder will be of name as given to the Zip when zipped up. Thus, I prefer the command as suggested in this answer

Answer (score 97):

Inside the folder you want to be compressed, in terminal:

```
zip -r -X Archive.zip *
```

Where -X means: Exclude those invisible Mac resource files such as “_MACOSX” or “._Filename” and .ds store files

[source](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-compress-and-uncompress-files-and-folders-in-os-x-lion-10-7-using-terminal/)

**Note:** Will only work for the folder and subsequent folder tree you are in and has to have the `*` wildcard.

Comment: This does not work as you think it does: `-X` does not exclude .DS_Store files.  The reason it may work for your application is that you're only zipping `*`, which is a wildcard matching files that don't begin with ".".  Try it on a directory containing a dot-file, and you'll see it gets included.

Comment: See my answer for an easy way to delete the _MACOSX folder after the zip file is created.

Comment: No. Doing `zip -r -X Archive.zip myfolder` on a folder still results in a zip file containing .DS_Store file.

Comment: @Rockallite: you are correct this will only work when you zip the folders, tree or files in the folder you are in. Hence you cannot pass a folder as an argument or it won't work as expected, only with the * wildcard will it work.

Comment: This works for files inside directories, instead of zipping a complete folder.

Comment: Also see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239578/compress-without-ds-store-and-macosx

Answer (score 47):

This command did it for me:

```
zip -r Target.zip Source -x "*.DS_Store"
```

`Target.zip` is the zip file to create. `Source` is the source file/folder to zip up. The `-x` parameter specifies the file/folder to exclude.

If the above doesn't work for whatever reason, try this instead:

```
zip -r Target.zip Source -x "*.DS_Store" -x "__MACOSX"
```

Comment: The OP asked how to exclude the __MACOSX folder.  Your first code snippet obviously doesn't work, because it doesn't name that as a folder to exclude.

Comment: The `zip` command line utility never creates a `__MACOSX` directory, so the first snippet does work, and the `-x "__MACOSX"` part is not needed.

Answer (score 20):

I'm using this Automator Shell Script to fix it after.
It's showing up as contextual menu item (right clicking on any file showing up in Finder).

```
while read -r p; do
  zip -d "$p" __MACOSX/\* || true
  zip -d "$p" \*/.DS_Store || true
done
```

1. Create a new Service with Automator
2. Select "Files and Folders" in "Finder"
3. Add a "Shell Script Action"

[image: automator shell script]

[image: contextual menu item in Finder]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do the compressing using zip in the Automator Shell Script, rather than compress using Apple built-in, then remove unwanted files?

Comment: @Matt you can add the archive step in automator or use another shell command as well.

Comment: @Matt also, Apple built-in handles automatic file naming and name increment when file exists. With shell script this part would be a lot of work.

Comment: It throws an error if the .DS_Store folder is not present in the archive. I suggest an improvement by adding ` || true` after each zip command (such as `zip -d "$p" __MACOSX/\* || true` into your answer.

Comment: While the other answers are good, I like this one best because it can be used in a very Macish way.

Answer (score 15):

```
zip -r "$destFileName.zip" "$srcFileName" -x "*/\__MACOSX" -x "*/\.*"
```

- `-x "*/\__MACOSX"`: ignore __MACOSX as you mention.
- `-x "*/\.*"`: ignore any hidden file, such as .DS_Store .
- Quote the variable to avoid file if it's named with SPACE.

Also, you can build Automator Service to make it easily to use in Finder.
Check link below to see detail if you need.

[Github](https://github.com/pilisir/macOSzip)

Comment: Heh, the only correct answer amongst a sea of garbage, is also the one with the least votes. /sigh

Comment: It worked for me but I had to remove the quotes around and the dollar symbol before destFileName.zip and srcFileName

Answer (score 13):

The unwanted folders can be also be deleted by the following way:

```
zip -d filename.zip "__MACOSX*"
```

Works best for me

Answer (score 8):

You can't.

But what you can do is delete those unwanted folders after zipping. Command line `zip` takes different arguments where one, the `-d`, is for deleting contents based on a regex. So you can use it like this:

```
zip -d filename.zip __MACOSX/\*
```

Answer (score 7):

I have a better solution after read all of the existed answers. Everything could done by a workflow in a single right click.
**NO** additional software, **NO** complicated command line stuffs and **NO** shell tricks.

The automator workflow:

- Input: files or folders from any application.
- Step 1: Create Archive, the system builtin with default parameters.
- Step 2: Run Shell command, with input as parameters. Copy command below.

  `zip -d "$@" "__MACOSX/*" || true`

  `zip -d "$@" "*/.DS_Store" || true`

Save it and we are done! Just right click folder or bulk of files and choose workflow from services menu. Archive with no metadata will be created alongside.

IMAGE UPDATE: I chose "Quick Action" when creating a new workflow - here’s an English version of the screenshot:

[image]

[image: Sample]

Comment: This is the best solution! Thank you so much! I used the camera in Google Translate to verify some of the specific settings in this screenshot (because I can't read Chinese myself, unfortunately), but this works beautifully. It creates a clean Archive.zip in the same folder. Very good. :-)

Comment: @ErikvanderNeut sorry for the inconvenience, I just casually post a screenshot of my own configuration at that time  I'll update the answer later

Comment: It's all good man :-) I really like your solution, so thank you for posting it.

Comment: It would be better if you capture the screenshot in English.

Comment: @Anduin - just added a screenshot in English after reproducing this for my own workflow.

Answer (score 6):

The `zip` command line utility never creates a `__MACOSX` directory, so you can just run a command like this:

```
zip directory.zip -x \*.DS_Store -r directory
```

In the output below, `a.zip` which I created with the `zip` command line utility does not contain a `__MACOSX` directory, but `a 2.zip` which I created from Finder does.

```
$ touch a
$ xattr -w somekey somevalue a
$ zip a.zip a
  adding: a (stored 0%)
$ unzip -l a.zip
Archive:  a.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  01-02-16 20:29   a
 --------                   -------
        0                   1 file
$ unzip -l a\ 2.zip # I created `a 2.zip` from Finder before this
Archive:  a 2.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  01-02-16 20:29   a
        0  01-02-16 20:31   __MACOSX/
      149  01-02-16 20:29   __MACOSX/._a
 --------                   -------
      149                   3 files
```

`-x .DS_Store` does not exclude `.DS_Store` files inside directories but `-x \*.DS_Store` does.

The top level file of a zip archive with multiple files should usually be a single directory, because if it is not, some unarchiving utilites (like `unzip` and `7z`, but not Archive Utility, The Unarchiver, `unar`, or `dtrx`) do not create a containing directory for the files when the archive is extracted, which often makes the files difficult to find, and if multiple archives like that are extracted at the same time, it can be difficult to tell which files belong to which archive.

Archive Utility only creates a `__MACOSX` directory when you create an archive where at least one file contains metadata such as extended attributes, file flags, or a resource fork. The `__MACOSX` directory contains AppleDouble files whose filename starts with `._` that are used to store OS X-specific metadata. The `zip` command line utility discards metadata such as extended attributes, file flags, and resource forks, which also means that metadata such as tags is lost, and that aliases stop working, because the information in an alias file is stored in a resource fork.

Normally you can just discard the OS X-specific metadata, but to see what metadata files contain, you can use `xattr -l`. `xattr` also includes resource forks and file flags, because even though they are not actually stored as extended attributes, they can be accessed through the extended attributes interface. Both Archive Utility and the `zip` command line utility discard ACLs.

Comment: This only works for directories, not for a bunch of file inside a directory.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw Yes, but you should not usually create an archive that contains multiple files at the top level in the first place.

Comment: I agree to disagree because there are use cases where this is fine. For example, one in which the end user of a zipfile will never be a user. But a server.

Answer (score 6):

Cleanup .zip from `.DS_Store` and `__MACOSX`, including subfolders:

```
zip -d archive.zip '__MACOSX/*' '*/__MACOSX/*' .DS_Store '*/.DS_Store'
```

Walkthrough:

1. Create .zip as usual by right-clicking on the file (or folder) and selecting "Compress ..."
2. Open Terminal app (search Terminal in Spotlight search)
3. Type `zip`  in the Terminal (but don't hit enter)
4. Drag .zip to the Terminal so it converts to the path
5. Copy paste `-d '__MACOSX/*' '*/__MACOSX/*' .DS_Store '*/.DS_Store'`
6. Hit enter
7. Use `zipinfo archive.zip` to list files inside, to check (optional)

Answer (score 2):

do not zip any hidden file:

```
zip newzipname filename.any  -x "\.*"
```

with this question, it should be like:

```
zip newzipname filename.any  -x "\__MACOSX"
```

It must be said, though, zip command runs in terminal just compressing the file, it does not compress any others. So do this the result is the same:

```
zip newzipname filename.any
```

Comment: `__MACOSX` does not start with `.`

Comment: yeah, I made a mistake. It has been modified. Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 2):

[Keka](https://www.keka.io) does this. Just drag your directory over the app screen.

[image]

Comment: Note that it's specifically the "Exclude Mac resource forks" checkbox that prevents the folder and files from being created in the archive.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the `zip` command-line tool or the Finder's Compress command?

For `zip`, you can try the `--data-fork` option. If that doesn't do it, you might try `--no-extra`, although that seems to ignore other file metadata that might be valuable, like uid/gid and file times.

For the Finder's Compress command, I don't believe there are any options to control its behavior. It's for the simple case.

The other tool, and maybe the one that the Finder actually uses under the hood, is `ditto`. With the `-c -k` options, it creates zip archives.  With this tool, you can experiment with `--norsrc`, `--noextattr`, `--noqtn`, `--noacl` and/or simply leave off the `--sequesterRsrc` option (which, according to the man page, may be responsible for the `__MACOSX` subdirectory).  Although, perhaps the absence of `--sequesterRsrc` simply means to use AppleDouble format, which would create ._ files all over the place instead of one `__MACOSX` directory.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the finder's "Compress" utility. As it is, I'm getting a folder full of ._ files which screws up WordPress' appearance/editor

Answer (score 0):

This is how i avoid the `__MACOSX` directory when compress files with `tar` command:

`$ cd dir-you-want-to-archive
$ find . | xargs xattr -l      # <- list all files with special xattr attributes
...
./conf/clamav: com.apple.quarantine: 0083;5a9018b1;Safari;9DCAFF33-C7F5-4848-9A87-5E061E5E2D55
./conf/global: com.apple.quarantine: 0083;5a9018b1;Safari;9DCAFF33-C7F5-4848-9A87-5E061E5E2D55
./conf/web_server: com.apple.quarantine: 0083;5a9018b1;Safari;9DCAFF33-C7F5-4848-9A87-5E061E5E2D55`

Delete the attribute first:

`find . | xargs xattr -d com.apple.quarantine`

Run `find . | xargs xattr -l` again, make sure no any file has the xattr attribute. then you're good to go:

`tar cjvf file.tar.bz2 dir`

Answer (score 0):

Another shell script that could be used with the Automator tool (see also benedikt's answer on how to create the script) is:

```
while read -r f; do
    d="$(dirname "$f")"
    n="$(basename "$f")"
    cd "$d"
    zip "$n.zip" -x \*.DS_Store -r "$n"
done
```

The difference here is that this code directly compresses selected folders without macOS specific files (and not first compressing and afterwards deleting).