# How to remove hidden MacOS files from a zip file?

Tags: macos, zip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When creating a zip file on MacOS it will result in many hidden MacOS files in the zip archive. These files are problematic when uploading an application to Amazon via Elastic Beanstalk.

How do I remove these hidden files from a zip file created on MacOS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac zip compress without \_\_MACOSX folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924236/mac-zip-compress-without-macosx-folder)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command that can be used to delete the hidden MacOS files from the zip file are as follows:

```
zip -d filename.zip __MACOSX/\*
```