# Microsoft Custom Translator: "The document '._..._...txt' is not a valid text file as it contains one or more invalid characters"

Tags: macos, zip, microsoft-translator, machine-translation, data-files

When using the [zip file format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/document-formats-naming-convention#zip-file-formats) to combine two parallel files, after data file upload we get the error message:

```
The document '._{name}_{lang}.txt' is not a valid {type} file as it contains one or more invalid characters.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that MacOS includes system files in the ZIP archive, and Microsoft tries to read them as data files because of the language suffix and .txt extension.

```
unzip -l data1.zip
```

```
Archive:  data1.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  04-09-2020 00:57   data1/
108746839  04-08-2020 23:55   data1/data_en.txt
      120  04-08-2020 23:55   __MACOSX/data1/._data_en.txt
126795036  04-08-2020 23:56   data1/data_de.txt
      120  04-08-2020 23:56   __MACOSX/data1/._data_de.txt
---------                     -------
235542115                     5 files
```

The fix is to compress them in a way that they are not added, or just remove them:

```
zip -d data1.zip __MACOSX*
zip -d data1.zip __DS_Store*
```

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239578/compress-without-ds-store-and-macosx, [Mac zip compress without __MACOSX folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924236/mac-zip-compress-without-macosx-folder)...

Thanks to [@ScottG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9808869/scottg) for debugging.